# Getting a list of all dates within a given date range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to figure out if there are any helper functions available or any techniques that might be helpful to get a list of dates within a given date range.

Lets say the user enters the following parameters which would be a 2 year contract:
**Day:** 15
**StartDate:** 1/15/2015
**EndDate:** 12/15/2016

I would expect the date for each month within that period including the start and end months to be returned:

```
1/15/2015
2/15/2015
3/15/2015
.....
1/15/2016
2/15/2016
3/15/2016
.....
12/15/2016
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setMonth` and `getMonth` methods:

> **Note:** As @RobG said in the comments, I made a mistake using a date format like this: `2015-12-01` for the example. The date format using `-` [is not interpreted by all browsers](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). It is better use the `/` character instead.

```js
const start = new Date('2015-01-15');
const end = new Date('2016-12-15');

while (start <= end) {
    console.log( new Date(start) );
    start.setMonth( start.getMonth() + 1 );
}
```

A more dynamic solution:

```js
function getDatesBtween(from, to, day) {

  const fromDate = new Date(from);
  const toDate = new Date(to);

  fromDate.setDate(day);
  toDate.setDate(day);

  const dates = [];

  while (fromDate <= toDate) {

    dates.push(new Date(fromDate));

    fromDate.setMonth(fromDate.getMonth() + 1);

  }

  return dates;

}

const dates = getDatesBtween('2015-01-15', '2016-12-15', 15);

console.log(dates);
```

> **Note:** As @HBP has mentioned in the comments, the above solution does not take in account edge cases and it does not  work with the last days of a month (`29th`, `30th` and `31st` days of the month). For example `2015/02/31` = `2015/03/03` in some cases and `2015/03/02` in others (in leap years). The next solution solves this problem:

```js
function DateManager() {

  // Create a date with specific day
  function setDate(date, day) {

    date = new Date(date);
    date.setDate(day);
    date.setHours(23);

    return date;

  }

  // Generate dates method
  this.getDatesBetween = function(date1, date2, day) {

    const range1 = new Date(date1);
    const range2 = new Date(date2);
    const dates = [];
    let temp = null;
    
    date1 = setDate(date1, day);
    date2 = setDate(date2, day);

    while (date1 <= date2) {

      if (date1.getDate() != day) {

        temp = setDate(date1, 0);

        if (temp >= range1 && temp <= range2) dates.push(temp);

        date1 = setDate(date1, day);

      } else {

        temp = new Date(date1);

        if (temp >= range1 && temp <= range2) dates.push(temp);

        date1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 1);

      }

    }

    return dates;

  };

}

const manager = new DateManager();
const dates = manager.getDatesBetween('2015-01-15', '2016-12-15', 31);

console.log(dates);
```

The result will be something like:

```
2015/01/31
2015/02/28
2015/03/31
2015/04/30
2015/05/31
...
2016/02/29
...
2016/11/30
```

Comment: I like this, but why is the 14th the day in all of the outputs. Lets say I want it to be the 15th of every month.

Comment: My result is with the 15 day in all outputs. If you write console.log(new Date("2015-10-15")); you get the 14th day?

Comment: Note that  browsers parse "2015-01-15" inconsistently. Some treat it as UTC, some as local and some will not parse it at all.

Comment: Consider the edge cases when the date is the 31st of the month, also the 29th and 30th for leap years.

Comment: You have the reason @HBP. I've updated my answer with a new version that solves that problem. Thanks for all ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#from").datepicker();
$("#to").datepicker();


$('#getBetween').on('click', function () {
    var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"),
        end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"),
        currentDate = new Date(start),
        between = []
    ;

    while (currentDate <= end) {
        between.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    
    $('#results').html(between.join('<br> '));
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />
<button id="getBetween">Get Between Dates</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: This is great, but gets the days in between, not the months.

Answer (score 1):

I think getDate() + 1 should be able to solve the boundary condition.

```
var startDate = new Date("2020-02-01"); //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = new Date("2020-03-07"); //YYYY-MM-DD

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start);
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);

// Output
document.write("Start Date: " + startDate + "<br>");
document.write("End Date: " + endDate + "<br>");
document.write("Date Array<br>")
for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
    document.write(dateArr[i] + "<br>");
}
```